# How to configure MainThread checker for your own code?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I have a class method that I want to always execute in the main thread.

Is there a way I could configure XCode Main Thread checker to raise a "purple warning" if that method is called on a background thread (just like it does for UI-related methods) ?

Comment: There're some [undocumented environment variables](https://bryce.co/main-thread-checker-configuration/), but they don't offer what you're looking for. I'm afraid it's not possible. Just add `assert(Thread.isMainThread, "You should run this on the main thread!")` (Swift) as a first line of your method and you're done.

Comment: Thanks - I was afraid I had to fallback to this...

Comment: I got a reply from an Apple engineer - _there's no documented way_. It can mean anything, there's no way, there's a way, ... He suggests to use `dispatchPrecondition(condition: .onQueue(.main))` instead of the assert.

Comment: Good job ! If you write that as an answer, I'll accept it with pleasure :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're some [undocumented environment variables](https://bryce.co/main-thread-checker-configuration/) like `MTC_SUPPRESSION_FILE` which allows you to provide a list of classes, methods & selectors to exclude from the checker. An opposite way to what you're looking for. I checked (quickly) the `libMainThreadChecker.dylib` and can't find more of them.

Then I got a reply from an Apple engineer - *there's no documented way*. It can mean anything - there's no way or there's a way, but it's not documented<sup>1</sup>. He suggests to just use ...

```swift
dispatchPrecondition(condition: .onQueue(.main))
```

... at the beginning of your method.

<sup>1</sup> The library is available at `/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib` if anyone wants to dig in.